# Read values from input fields on word document with code

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am so close in making this work. Basically I want to read input fields from a word document. In other words I have:

[image]

*Hello world* is the content of the label I placed by clicking on the *Aa* button that is also highlighted on the image. So when I save that document as `Test.docx` I do the following with code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application word = new ApplicationClass();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = @"a:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Test.docx";  // <-------- Path where document is
        object readOnly = false;
        Document document = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        // here I iterate through all the input fields!!!  <--------------------------
        foreach (ContentControl ff in document.ContentControls)
        {
            var m = ff.PlaceholderText; // for some reason I cannot get the text of the control.
            var b = ff.ShowingPlaceholderText;
            Console.WriteLine(ff.ToString());
        }

        document.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        word.Quit();
    }
}
```

I am able to iterate through all the input fields the only thing I am missing to do is get the value inside the control!

---

### Edit

**Finally found the solution** For some reason that property does not appear on the debugger! anyways to get the text of that control I had to do:

```
 Console.WriteLine(ff.Range.Text);
```

So my finall code now looks like:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application word = new ApplicationClass();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = @"a:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Test.docx";  // <-------- Path where document is
        object readOnly = false;
        Document document = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        foreach (ContentControl ff in document.ContentControls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ff.Range.Text);
        }

        document.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        word.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just suggesting: Office XML SDK, or even open the packaged .docx and search internal xml via xpath.